# DeserialzationContext instances piling up in the GC heap

Tags: .net, performance, web-services, garbage-collection, compact-framework

I am trying to trace a memory leak issue in a smart device application developed in `C# .NET CF 3.5`. I am using `.NET CF Remote Performance Monitor (RPM)`

The smart device app talks to another application via webservice hosted on the remote application. With every call to the web-service, RPM shows that a new instance of DeserializationContext[] array is being generated, any they aren't getting disposed unless the service-client is disposed, which is causing a GC heap build up.

What are these objects, and how can I dispose them after each call is executed?

Thank you.

[image: Object graph from Remote Performance Monitor]